# How do you create a unified inbox in IOS swift?

Tags: ios

I want multiple email accounts like gmail, yahoo, outlook and custom domain mail to be shown under one hood, i.e. a custom inbox/sent/trash of my creation? can anyone provide me any idea on what to look for or how to achieve this in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an open source library 'MailCore' which serves the purpose of sending/receiving emails programmatically.

Comment: this is a start I can work upon thanks.